# Xcode 4 exported app gives error 'Can't Open Application...Classic Environment Not supported'?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4

I made a simple app, archived it and went into organizer. From there I clicked Distribute -> Export As Application -> Don't Resign and then saved it to my desktop. It runs fine then, but if I upload it to Mediafire and try to download it I get the error `You can't open the application X because the Classic environment is no longer supported.` when trying to run it. I didn't change any default settings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How did you upload it? Did you wrap it in a zip archive or did you just upload the raw app bundle?

If you just uploaded the raw app then you will have destroyed the permissions and extended attributes on the executables, causing the app to fail to work when downloaded.

The system will see your main executable as a non-executable file, and the "Classic Environment" error message is just the default error message in this situation as it's the most likely reason for this issue.

Wrapping the app in a zip works because the zip format retains the permissions information for the files in the zip archive.

Comment: This answer should have like 100 upvotes from cocoa newb's :)

Answer (score 0):

Hm for whatever reason I had to zip up the file before uploading it. Don't know exactly why, but that works.

Comment: See my answer. Executable files must have specific access privileges in order for the system to know that they are executable. If you upload the app bundle via some system that does not preserve the permissions on each file, when you download the files again all of the files in the bundle will have default privileges, including the app's main executable.